# python print command in same open window not in prompt

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

Ok so i am trying my hand in python and ran into a issue with this little app i am trying to put together. I am trying to have a window open on run and ask for a keyword input, then match that input to a any line in a file. I enter the input and press show, but the results don't show or show in the prompt. I need to have the results show in the open window. possibly on a new row and column that is created when the show button is pressed. so the results show in the window only, I am on a ubuntu based system. Here is my app .py file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# sets the name settings
from Tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()

# runs the script to get full 
# list of programs for matching
#subprocess.call(["listcmnd.sh"])

# create the application
myapp = App()

# sets the e1 variable
e1 = Entry(myapp)

# checks keyword agianst 
# programs in the sam.txt file
import re

keyword = open("results/program_files/sam.txt", "r")

for line in keyword:
if re.match("str(text)", line):
    print line,

# prints results of keyword entry match
def show_entry_fields():
print("Program Name: %s" % (e1.get()))

# gives the output of findings
from Tkinter import *

# asks for search critiria
text = Label(myapp, text="Keyword: ").grid(row=0)

# displays the buttons for getting 
# results and closing program
Button(myapp, text='Quit', command=myapp.quit).grid(row=3, column=0,     sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(myapp, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

# prints results of keyword entry match
def show_entry_fields():
print("Program Name: %s" % (e1.get()))

# displays the text entry field
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

#
# here are method calls to the window manager class
#
myapp.master.title("Program Search Tool")
myapp.master.maxsize(1000, 400)

# start the program
myapp.mainloop()
```

ok so i made a few alterations to the main script but still outputs results to terminal and not in the open window

Here is new code alterations

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  # sets the name settings
  from Tkinter import *
  class App(Frame):
      def __init__(self, master=None):
         Frame.__init__(self, master)
          self.pack()

  # runs the script to get full 
  # list of programs for matching
  #subprocess.call(["listcmnd.sh"])

  # create the application
  myapp = App()

  # sets the e1 variable
  e1 = Entry(myapp)

  # checks keyword agianst 
  # programs in the sam.txt file
  import re

  keyword = open("results/program_files/sam.txt", "r")

  for line in keyword:
    if re.match("get()(text)", line):
          print line,

  # prints results of keyword entry match
  def show_entry_fields():
    print("Program Name: %s" % (e1.get()))

  # asks for search critiria
  # displays the text entry field
  e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
  text = Label(myapp, text="Program Name: ")
  text.grid(row=3, column=0)

  # displays the buttons for getting 
  # results and closing program
  Button(myapp, text='Quit', command=myapp.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
  Button(myapp, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)

  #
  # here are method calls to the window manager class
  #
  myapp.master.title("Program Search Tool")
  myapp.master.maxsize(1000, 1000)
  myapp.master.minsize(50, 50)

  # start the program
  myapp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a label (or maybe create it before and update it) in function

```
def show_entry_fields():
```

Additional remarks:

you import Tkinter several times

you also define def show_entry_fields(): twice

```
text = Label(myapp, text="Keyword: ").grid(row=0)
```

doesn't work. You must write:

```
 text = Label(myapp, text="Keyword: ")
 text.grid(row=0)
```

Comment: ok so i removed the double tkinter and define show_entry_fields.

Comment: can you give me an example to create a label? I am not sure how to do that being my first time working with python. I also not sure if this will help place the results in the open window. can you please give an example of it thanks

Comment: text = Label(myapp, text="Keyword: ")
text.grid(row= 4)
You place it inside the show_entry_fields function.

Comment: 1) Have you tried to write something with my indications? 2) Did it work?
3) Post what you wrote at the end of your question, and the result.

Comment: Ok Eric i tried the example but still not doing it.  guess i am just a little confused on working with python, lol. go figure...  right now my python app code is as follows but like i said i want it to post results in the open window not on the command line as it is doing now..

Comment: You made a good first step. Now you need to: 1) create a label, say text2 (and "grid" it) 2) in function show_entry_fields, declare text2 as global then update its value with text2['text'] = "Program Name: %s" % (e1.get())

Comment: Eric -------- so if i do this then It should show the program name in the window  where it would say program name: then the program actual name and not in the terminal window running in the back ground to catch errors in the code it self.?

Comment: Yes. (and I add this because you cannot post a comment that said yes)